# Is direct keyboard shortcut access to menu bar items possible on macOS?

Tags: macos, windows, menu-bar, accessibility

How can I focus top menu:
[image]
On Windows after clicking alt button one can see letters being underlined, which are required to push to open chosen menu.
How can I open File menu without using a mouse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mac doesn't have a direct equivalent.

You can use  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>F2</kbd>  to move focus to the Menu Bar, then use letters &/or arrow keys to jump to specific locations in there.

[image]

It is usually simpler though, for an often-used command, to just set up a specific hot key for it, if it doesn't already have one.

[image]